# How to iterate and print the properties of a java form object in java script?

Tags: javascript, java

I have a map of type 
`Map<String,UserForm>` 
where

```
Class UserForm {
String userName;
String password;
//setters ;
//getters;
}

Map<String,UserForm> userMap=new HashMap<String,UserForm>();
```

I am adding `userMap` to a json object and sending the object to a JSP page in an ajax call. In javascript, I need to iterate through the `userMap` and print its properties (userName and password).

This is what I have done so far

```
for(var i in ajaxResponseData.userMap)
{
 if (ajaxResponseData.userMap.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
alert(' Value is: ' + ajaxResponseData.userMap[i].userName);
}
```

But the above way is showing undefined in the alert box. Please help..

Comment: tried: `...'Value is: ' + i.userName);` ??  (but th `if` and the "access" seem strange)

Comment: You should see what json you are getting as response. What I see from your code is, you will not get json with node userMap.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest double-checking that the response data is coming back in the format you're expecting and then trying to access it. Also, I believe there's no need to check if it has property `i`, as you are already iterating over it (thus it has been found).. Try the following snippet of code:

```
console.log(ajaxResponseData.userMap); // to see how your data actually looks like

for (var i in ajaxResponseData.userMap) {
  // use the key to access the element
  console.log(ajaxResponseData.userMap[i]); // is this the value you're looking for?
}
```

I have also setup a small example in JsFiddle, that alerts the values: https://jsfiddle.net/kd7u4zLt/

Comment: Upon printing the map in console as suggested the following line is printed. Object1: "com.bank.form.UserForm@b8fc87"
__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 2name:...

Comment: This doesn't look like the appropriate JSON-like object map that you need. I would read into parsing the server response successfully and once you have a proper object, then you could iterrate and acess the elements. Please provide more code of the part reiceiving & handling the response in your script?